# Pin numbering in OrCAD?

Tags: pcb, orcad, allegro

I'm getting another error in OrCAD when I try to create the netlist. When I try to create the netlist I get this warning:

> 1. ERROR(ORCAP-36022): Pin number missing from Pin "DRIVE" of Package 100301_7 , U10A: SCHEMATIC1, PAGE1 (6.37, 0.95). All pins should be
>      numbered.
> 2. ERROR(ORCAP-36022): Pin number missing from Pin "BAT" of Package 100301_7 , U10A: SCHEMATIC1, PAGE1 (6.37, 0.95). All pins should be
>      numbered.
> 3. ERROR(ORCAP-36022): Pin number missing from Pin "SENSE" of Package 100301_7 , U10A: SCHEMATIC1, PAGE1 (6.37, 0.95). All pins should be
>      numbered.
> 4. ERROR(ORCAP-36022): Pin number missing from Pin "TIMER" of Package 100301_7 , U10A: SCHEMATIC1, PAGE1 (6.37, 0.95). All pins should be
>      numbered.
> 5. ERROR(ORCAP-36022): Pin number missing from Pin "!SHDN" of Package 100301_7 , U10A: SCHEMATIC1, PAGE1 (6.37, 0.95). All pins should be
>      numbered.
> 6. ERROR(ORCAP-36022): Pin number missing from Pin "PAUSE" of Package 100301_7 , U10A: SCHEMATIC1, PAGE1 (6.37, 0.95). All pins should be
>      numbered.

There is a total of 35 instances of this error. I don't understand the error though. If I go into edit part for U10A, all the pins are already numbered. So I don't see where else these pins should be numbered?

Comment: Was your previous question or orcad answered to your needs?

Comment: My previous question was answered, but this is a different error that appears when I try to create the netlist. Before I was getting an error why I ran the DRC.

Comment: can you give a screenshot of one of those pins EDIT screen (under part edit). You will probably find the number wasn't added to the box orcad expects

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was, but I ended up creating the part from scratch and the error went away. I was initially editing a different part and saving it as the new part that I was working with.

Comment: If the previous question has been answered then please mark it as being so.

Answer (score 1):

Does your part have both pin names and pin numbers like this?  In the case of the picture below the numbers inside the part are the pin names and the numbers on the pins are the pin numbers.

[image]

Comment: In your case you should see say pause on the inside of the chip, and then the pin number for pause on the pin.

Comment: Right, so I had the names of the pins on the inside, such as Vcc, GND, Drive, Prog, etc. The Pin numbers showed up as shown on your image on the outside.

Comment: How did you set the PIN number?

Comment: Or just put a link to your Dsn file and or your .olb file where the part is

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/li9ztgnocouj8g4/RECHARGEABLE%20BATTERY.DSN?dl=0

Comment: I've fixed my error by making the new part from scratch. But the component that was giving me problems was on page 1, component U10A. I was getting an error for each pin, and I don't actually know what solved the problem because in the new part I layed out the pins the same way as when I just edited a component.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't see a u10 in that schematic you posted so that's the fixed one?

Answer (score 1):

I created my own part from scratch instead of trying to edit a pre-existing part and this helped in getting rid of my error.